# How to copy additional files on build?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a WebApi2 application and it references other projects within the solution. One of these includes some files that I want copied on build. These files have their `Copy to Output Directory` property set to true.

The files are correctly located in the bin folder of their assembly.

However:

1. After the build I need them to be copied to the App_Data folder of the web application
2. Included in the files that get published to IIS

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Add build events

In Visual Studio -> Solution Explorer -> right click the project -> properties -> go to build events.

Use something like [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

Also if click on "Edit Post-Build" you will see a list of useful folders and file names which you can use e.g. $(OutDir)

[image: Build Events]

Comment: You have provided only half the solution. It is unlikely the person knows how to use Xcopy or is even aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you are going to have to get your hands dirty with MSBuild. Its been ages since I've used it but you will need to use the [Move Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595163.aspx)

This is what Visual Studio uses in the background to build the projects. It may seem daunting but is actually pretty simple once you get used to it. There are tons of tutorials online.

Alternatively, and the most straightforward way, is that you include the files in the APP_DATA folder from within the solution.

EDIT: As mentioned by **robor78** you will need to call the **Move Task** in the **Post-Build** event

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xcopy from the Post build event. It is pretty straight forward but will not run if code not changed. So if you update configs etc. you must force the build I beleive.

See here for how to use xcopy.
http://commandwindows.com/xcopy.htm

There are wild cards and all kinds of useful features, but your situation is pretty simple. Just copy from $(ProjectDir)/bin or something like that to a path.